# How can we get the activity for callback binding (in a fragment) in firebase phone authentication method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, fragment

Though I used this, getActivity(), getContext() & etc. But no luck.

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                "91" + mobile,
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                this,
                mCallbacks
        );
```

Comment: paste the full code of fragment and callback. the normal getContext should work if you define the callback inside fragment or you should pass it as variable.

Comment: I didn't use the callback method in the main activity causing it not to work. I changed it and now I am good. Thanks for your response.